# How can I change a property value in the original object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to create a function that accesses and reassigns the value of a property in an object. However, each new time I invoke the function the function the previous changes I made with it are not kept in the object (it returns to its original state). So each time I use the function it is only making the change once, and each new time I use it the old changes are not kept and only the new request is visible in the output.

Below is some of my code

```
class Shoes {
  constructor(name, productCode, quantity, valuePerItem) {
    this.name = name;
    this.productCode = productCode;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.valuePerItem = valuePerItem;
  }

//Excuse all the commented out code in the function below, but I am trying multiple approaches
static changeValue(array, index, property, content) {
    // //holds array of objects
    // let a = array;
    // //holds specific object in array
    // let i = shoesArray[index];
    // //holds name of property user entered
    // let p = property;
    // //holds property value
    // let targetProperty = i[p];

    shoesArray[index][property] = content;

    // console.table(newObjArray);
    console.table(shoesArray);
    // console.log(a, i, p, targetProperty);
    // console.table();
  }
}

//Below 5 instances of a shoe object have been created.
let myShoes1 = new Shoes("Adiddas", 001, 3, 25);
let myShoes2 = new Shoes("Nike", 002, 6, 30);
let myShoes3 = new Shoes("Puma", 003, 2, 20);
let myShoes4 = new Shoes("Vans", 004, 7, 30);
let myShoes5 = new Shoes("Converse", 005, 9, 40);

//Below I have created an array for shoes and have populated it with each object.
let shoesArray = [];
shoesArray.push(myShoes1);
shoesArray.push(myShoes2);
shoesArray.push(myShoes3);
shoesArray.push(myShoes4);
shoesArray.push(myShoes5);

console.table(shoesArray);

//Below I am calling the function.
Shoes.changeValue(shoesArray, 3, "quantity", 100);
```

So I have tried simply re-assigning the property value, it returns a new table with the new change. But when I run the code again with a new change it doesnt keep the previous change it only makes a new change to the original array of objects.

I am rather new to coding. I know there are some similar questions on here to this one but I am struggling to understand the application of this technique to my particular code.

Thanks for the time and patience.

Comment: If you want persistent changes, invoke `new` once.

Comment: @zer00ne where do you mean I should invoke this? When creating the objects? Im not sure. Thank you!

Comment: `new` creates an instance of an Object. If you use `new` again then that is a entirely different Object that doesn't have any of the changes any previously created Object.

Comment: @zer00ne Yes but I've only used them once to create each new shoe object and then stored those objects in an array. Where am I using it twice?

Comment: Are you referring to the code that's commented out and says, *"Excuse all the commented out code in the function below,..."*?

Comment: @zer00ne well that commented out code works to change the value of the object once. But when I run the code again only the new change is shown, the previous change is not there anymore and I dont know why..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249152/discussion-between-zer00ne-and-coderinneed).